# Remove border lines on geom_smooth confidence interval using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, border, plotly

I'm building a pretty intensive plot, but I am having a basic problem with `geom_smooth` that I can't seem to find any answers for. Here's how the plot looks now with `geom_smooth(method = "lm")` :

[image]

When I build the `geom_smooth()` portion of my plot, I'd like to change the line color. When I do this, it draws new lines bordering my confidence interval,

Calling `geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "black")` returns this:

[image]

Is there a simple way to get rid of the border lines, but keep the main line black?

EDIT: I can't provide full code with data, but have provided circumstances that will reproduce the error here. You will need no more than this to answer the question. Per the comments below, its likely an interaction with plotly (`ggplotly`).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(
    Demographic = rnorm(1:100),
    Proficiency = rnorm(1:100),
    N.Tested = rnorm(1:100)
)

a <- ggplot(data = df, 
        aes(x = Demographic, 
            y = Proficiency)
)
b <- a + geom_point(aes(
    text = "to be replaced",
    color = N.Tested,
    size = N.Tested
),
show.legend = FALSE)
c <- b + scale_color_gradient2(low = "firebrick4", high = "gold", mid = "orange", midpoint=300)
d <- c + geom_smooth(method = "lm", color="black")

ggplotly(d)
```

Comment: Can you show the full code for your plot (and maybe some sample data)? I'm trying to figure out where the borders are coming from, as that's not the default behavior. For example, this doesn't produce borders around the confidence interval: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour=hp)) +  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", colour="black") `.

Comment: Agree with @eipi10. we need to see the full code + data. This behaviour seems odd

Comment: Excellent point, my mistake. The fix below wasn't working for me either, so it must be something outside of ggplot.

My best guess now is that it's an interaction with `ggplotly()`. Full code is included in edit above.

Comment: so this is the output from ggplotly not ggplot??? That's a completely different scenario. Btw - I still don't see the **full code** or any data - I.e. what we need is all the lines required to cut and paste into a console and reproduce what you have

Comment: This is why we ask for a **[reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)** (that is, code + data that reproduces your issue) with every question. It often saves a lot of time.

Comment: Please forgive my transgression. I have updated the code and simulated data in a way that will allow you to copy and paste it into your console. Please not that you will have to have both ggplot2 and plotly installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add just the regression line via `geom_smooth` and add the ribbon via `geom_ribbon` using `stat = "smooth"`.  It adds an extra step but separating the layers allows you to color the line without messing up the confidence ribbon.

```
d <- c + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "black")
e <- d + geom_ribbon(stat = "smooth", method = "lm", alpha = .15)
ggplotly(e)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew there was a way to separate the commands, just didn't know the commands. Simple and elegant, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`ggplotly` frequently gives unexpected results. If the end product you want is a plotly graph, then it's usually best to go straight to the plotly API. Using the plotly API also gives access to a much wider range of options than ggplotly.

Unfortunately, however, plotly does not come with the convenient built in calculation of statistics that `geom_smooth` provides. So we begin by calculating our fit and error range using `lm()` and `predict.lm()`

```
lm1 = lm(Proficiency~Demographic, data=df)
lm.df = data.frame(Demographic = sort(df$Demographic), 
                   Proficiency = predict(lm1)[order(df$Demographic)],
                   se = predict(lm1, se.fit = T)$se.fit[order(df$Demographic)])
lm.df$ymax = lm.df$Proficiency + lm.df$se
lm.df$ymin = lm.df$Proficiency - lm.df$se
```

Now we are ready to plot, using the plotly API directly

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data=df, x=~Demographic, y=~Proficiency, type="scatter", mode="markers",
            size=~N.Tested, color=~N.Tested, colors = c("#8B1A1A", "#FFA500"), showlegend=F) %>%
  add_ribbons(data=lm.df, x=~Demographic, ymin = ~ymin, ymax = ~ymax,
              line = list(color="transparent"), showlegend=F,
              fillcolor = "#77777777") %>%
  add_trace(data=lm.df, x=~Demographic, y=~Proficiency, 
          type="scatter", mode="lines", line=list(color="black"), showlegend=F)
```

[image]

Comment: It might still work if you set `inherit.aes = F` for `geom_smooth` and respecify the x and y aesthetics.